# Angular : toFixed() works with one value but not with the other?

Tags: angular, typescript, tofixed

I'm using a form with 2 inputs. Each of them call the `calculeSalaire()` function.

```
calculeSalaire()
{
  this.fraisGestion = this.getFraisGestion();
  this.tauxFraisGestion = this.getTauxFraisGestion();
  this.salaireBrut = this.getSalaireBrut();
  this.salaireNet = this.getSalaireNet();
  this.chargesSalariales = this.getChargesSalariales();
  this.chargesPatronales = this.getChargesPatronales();
  this.totalPaye = this.getTotalPaye();
}
```

All of these functions return `number`. I want to show only 2 decimal places for each of these values, that's why I use the `toFixed(2)` function.

It works for all my functions except for this one :

```
getSalaireBrut()
{
   this.salaireBrut = (this.chiffreAffaire - this.fraisGestion - 
   this.fraisPro)/(1.10)/(1.447);

   var salaireBruttxt = this.salaireBrut.toFixed(2);

   return parseFloat(salaireBruttxt);
}
```

`chiffreAffaire` is an Input

`fraiPro` is an Input

`fraisGestion` is calculated

I don't understand why it doesn't work for the previous function, whereas it works in the function below.

```
getChargesSalariales()
  {
    this.chargesSalariales = this.salaireBrut*(23/100);
    var chargesSalarialtxt = this.chargesSalariales.toFixed(2);

    return parseFloat(chargesSalarialtxt);
  }
```

You can note that I use the `salaireBrut` value which is the one calculated by the function that didn't work.

Do you have any ideas why this happens ?

Comment: try coercing the input into a number, or better yet typing it as one. I suspect it is a string in your example.

Comment: Also you can use your input numbers in calculations by wrapping `Number(this.chargesSalariales).toFixed(2)`  Number is accepting both of string and number and creates a number

Comment: Both inputs were typed as number. 
My problem was due to a call to the `getSalaireBrut()` function in an other function. I don't really get why but it kind of override the value with 2 decimals.
Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toFixed` function returns a string, as a number won't ever keep or show trailing zeros. Therefore what happens is that the `toFixed` actually works totally fine in your function (you can easily check this when you put a breakpoint there), however the `parseFloat` makes it a number again, which never ever contains trailing zeros as I said before.

So you actually have to return a string there - removing the `parseFloat` will solve the issue.

Comment: Indeed the `parseFloat` function is useless here.
My probleme was a bit strange, in fact I used the `getSalaireBrut()` function in an other function and it kind of override the correct value (with 2 decimals).
By replacing `this.getSalaireBrut()` by `this.salaireBrut` everything is Ok !
Thank you for your help !